# How can we create a NSWindow in Javascript for automation (mac JXA)?

Tags: javascript-automation

I would like to use JavaScript for automation (mac JXA) to make a NSWindow and show it to the user.

I tried following [this](https://github.com/tylergaw/js-osx-app-examples/tree/master/ChooseAndDisplayImage.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts) example, but it crashes when I run it in the Script Editor app.

Then I tried to make my own using barebones.  As a start I just want a window with a title in it.

```
ObjC.import("Cocoa")

var window = $.NSWindow.alloc.init
window.setContentSize($.NSMakeSize(500, 500))
window.title = "hello world"
window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
```

When I try to run this in Script Editor the app crashes right away.  It appears to be crashing when I try to initialize the NSWindow Object.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I followed [this guide](https://tylergaw.com/articles/building-osx-apps-with-js/) and they say you have to save it as an application and run it as an application.

Heres a clip where they mention it in the article.
[image]